# Testing using hapijs/lab -- done is not a function

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Trying to write some tests for my hapi server. The following code is from https://github.com/hapijs/lab/issues/79 , but it's failing because done is not a function...

```
const Code = require('code');
const Lab = require('lab');
const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
lab.test('expect an error from a promise', (done) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        try {
            resolve(2);
        }
        catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    }).then((result) => {

        console.log('5) resolved');
        done(new Error('promise should be rejected and caught'));
    }).catch((error) => {

        console.log('5) rejected, this does not trigger');
        Code.expect(error).to.exist();
        done(error);
    });
});
```

What else should I import to be able to call done?

```
Failed tests:

  1) expect an error from a promise:

      done is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lab.test` does not return the `done` callback anymore since its compatible with hapi v17.
Lab uses async/await features now and you can return promises.
See here for an example: [lab docs](https://github.com/hapijs/lab)

Answer (score 0):

**`"lab": "^14.3.4"`** seems to still support **`done`** and **es6** at the same time. Of course, I cannot confirm that the full set of es6 features is supported but it satisfied my needs.